# Como criar uma interseção com complexidade em O(n)?

Tags: c, c++

Necessito criar uma função que faz a **interseção** entre dois vetores: `vetorA` **∩** `vetorB` e aloca os valores encontrados nesta interseção em um `vetorC`!

**Regras:**

- **a)** A complexidade da função/método intersecao deve ser, obrigatoriamente:

  **O(n)**, se `n > m`

  **O(m)**, se `m > n`
- **b)** A assinatura da função de interseção deve ser, obrigatoriamente:

  `void intersecao(char a[], int n, char b[], int m, char c[], int *k)`
- **c)** Não podem ser usadas funções predefinidas das linguagens para tratamento
  dos vetores (busca, pertinência, inserção, exclusão, ordenação, etc.).

Eu estava pensando em utilizar um algoritmo de complexidade **O(n)** o qual é denominado **"Tempo linear"**. Porém este algoritmo ele faz a comparação **"linear" obviamente como o nome diz**.

**Exemplo:**

```
A = { 'E', 'C', 'B', 'J', 'S', 'F', 'C', 'V', 'G' }
B = { 'G', 'C', 'M', 'W', 'L', 'O' }
C = { 'G', 'C' }
```

**Qual a minha dificuldade?**

> Estou tentando desenvolver uma lógica que atenda a complexidade pedida **O(n)** e **O(m)**, porém estou com dificuldade em pegar um determinado elemento de um determinado vetor, percorrer com este elemento, comparando todo o outro determinado vetor. A única solução que consigo pensar seria pelo menos um **O(n²).**

**Ilustração do que estou tentando fazer:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**MEU CÓDIGO:**

```
bool checkHasStringEqual(char vectorA, char vectorB) {
    string stringA, stringB;
    stringA = toupper(vectorA),
    stringB = toupper(vectorB);

    size_t found = stringA.find(stringB);

    return (found != std::string::npos);
}

void intersection(char a[], char b[], char c[], int n, int m, int *k){
    cout << "VETOR [A]: {" << a << "}" << endl;
    cout << "VETOR [B]: {" << b << "}\n\n" << endl;

    if(n > m) {
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (checkHasStringEqual(a[i], b[index]) && !checkHasStringEqual(b[index], c[index])) {
                k = new int[strlen(c) + 1];
                c[k] = b[index];

                i = 0;
                index++;

                cout << "EH IGUAL: " << a[i] << " == " << b[index] << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    if(m > n) {
        //CÓDIGO
    }
}
```

Comment: não acredito que seja possível fazer isso em O(n)...meu palpite é O(m*n), que não é ruim, acho eu

Comment: @zentrunix è possível fazer com o algoritmo que citei acima, porém ele busca e compara linearmente por exemplo: a[0] == b[0], a[1] == b[1] e por aí vai, eu preciso tentar modifica-lo para que  “trave” o índice de um vetor e busque e compare tudo por exemplo a[0] == b[0] , a[1] == b[0] e por aí vai.

Comment: Creio que você só consiga fazer tal algoritmo se ambos os vetores estiverem ordenados. Aí vira um problema de linha balanceada.

Comment: @anonimo e ai amigo, tudo bem? Eu acabei de responder a minha pergunta também com o algoritmo já pronto, obrigado por tudo!

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução alternativa seria criar um vetor de `bool` para informar se determinado elemento consta, ou não, no vetorA. Em seguida, lê-se o vetorB e todos os elementos de B que também constassem em A seriam imediatamente inseridos no vetorC. Algo do tipo:

```
#include <iostream>

void intersecao(char a[], int n, char b[], int m, char c[], int *k) {

    //cada uma das posições do vetor representa um letra maiúscula
    bool letras[26] = { false };

    /*Primeiro, lê-se o vetor A, identificando-se as letras maiúsculas e, ao mesmo tempo, 
    alterando o valor do elemento correspondente no vetor letras[] para true.   
    DETALHE: em ASCII o número 65 equivale a letra A, então em 'a[1] - 65', há a conversão de ASCII para o índice do vetor letras, no qual A == 0.*/
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        letras[a[i] - 65] = true;
    }

    *k = 0;
    //Então, lê-se o vetor B e, caso a letra presente nesse vetor 
    //também conste no vetor A, ela é inserida no vetor C
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        if (letras[b[i] - 65]) {
            c[*k] = b[i];
            (*k)++;
            /*caso se deseje evitar a inserção de valores repetidos, pode-se inserir
            a seguinte instrução:
            letras[b[i] - 65] = false;*/
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    char A[] = { 'E', 'C', 'B', 'J', 'S', 'F', 'C', 'V', 'G' }; 

    char B[] = { 'G', 'C', 'M', 'W', 'L', 'O' };    

    char C[9];
    int k = 0;

    intersecao(A, 9, B, 6, C, &k);  

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        std::cout << C[i];
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Algumas observações: eu assumi que os vetores A e B somente conteriam letras maiúsculas. Então, é necessário observar que o código acima precisaria receber algumas modificações de segurança, ao menos para verificar os valores contidos nesses vetores, do contrário, a instrução `letras[a[i] - 65] = true` pode eventualmente escrever fora dos limites do array

(Observação: eu não inseri essas modificações de segurança, porque queria me focar no algorítimo. Além do mais como você usa a função `touper` acho que você não teria nenhuma dificuldade em fazer isso).

Ainda sobre o tipo de entrada: caso os vetores contivessem outros valores que não apenas letras maiúsculas. A solução poderia ser alterada e continuaria em O(n), se os elementos possíveis pudessem ser previamente conhecidos, embora o uso de memória pudesse se tornar um problema, por exemplo, se os vetores fossem compostos por `int32_t` bastaria alocar alguns gigabites para construir um vetor de bool para dar conta de todos os números inteiros possíveis nesse tipo.

Contudo, caso os elementos possíveis não pudessem ser previamente conhecidos, por exemplo, se A e B fossem vetores de `strings`, aí eu só consigo imaginar soluções do tipo O(nLogn), nas quais, deveria ser feita previamente a ordenação dos elementos dos vetores com algum algorítimo de ordenação eficiente.

Comment: você está percorrendo o vetor A (tamanho n) e depois o vetor B (tamanho m), isso implica que a complexidade vai ser O(n+m) e não O(n), como disse no comentário da pergunta...tá certo que a complexidade ainda é linear, o que é bom, mas é linear em A + B, e não apenas em A

Comment: @zentrunix, `o(n+m) = o(n)` nesse caso.

Comment: Se n > m, então O(m + n) = O(n + n) = O(n)
Se m > n, o resultado é análogo.

Comment: @zentrunix `O(n+m)` é igual a `O(n)`.